# Estimating distribution from pairwise comparisons (crowdsourced)

Tags: distributions, paired-data

I would like to estimate a discrete probability distribution, for instance, occurrences of animal species in a geographical area (e.g. from all the animals 20% are bears, 10% are wolfs, 5% are giraffes, etc.).

I would like to estimate the distribution by crowdsourcing, that is, asking experts to asses pairwise probabilities of occurrence (e.g. "what is more frequently occuring: a bear or a wolf?").

I am looking into methods for recovering distribution from pairwise comparisons. Suppose I have a matrix A of n x n species, where the entry a_ij = 1 if species i is more likely to occur than j, a_ij = -1 is species j is more likely to occur, and a_ij = 0 if the species are equally likely.

I can't find existing solutions for that, but maybe I just don't know the right keywords. Any related work to that?

Comment: My guess is that you won't be able to recover a distribution as such, but will be able to recover the predictive distribution for a hypothetical "average" expert's rankings. Some resources I found that might be helpful to that end: http://dollar.biz.uiowa.edu/~street/7536-32457-1-PB.pdf and http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/pauben/papers/wsdm2013-preference-chen-et-al.pdf

Comment: Also http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2690000/2685308/p253-niu.pdf?ip=24.184.148.127&id=2685308&acc=OPEN&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&CFID=626101104&CFTOKEN=75757049&__acm__=1423750560_45bb7846ce2ecf88b2cc13de7601aadb

Comment: Can't open the last link